# A .cshtml mix goes wrong

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I try to implement a loop displaying small boxes.. The following first code has for result this :

[image: second image]

(code) :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
    <!-- small box -->
    <!-- achtung hier soll man vielleicht die Adresse ändern -->

    @{for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListStations.Length; i++)
            {
                string urlTemp = Model.ListStations[i];
                string colorTemp = "small-box bg-" + Model.ListColors[i % Model.ListColors.Length];
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(colorTemp);
        <div class= "small-box bg-blue">
            <div class="inner">
                <h3>Station</h3>
                <p> Model.ListStations[i]</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
                <i class="fa fa-heartbeat" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <a href= @urlTemp class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
        </div>;
            }
        }
    </div>
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

But when I just change the `"small-box bg-blue"` into `@colorTemp`, a list containing `"small-box bg-blue"`, `"small-box bg-black"` and `"small-box bg-green"`, I get this :

[image: first image]

I suppose there is a subtle html specificity I missed (or not), has someone an idea what's going wrong ?
Edit : the generated HTML code is :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
        <!-- small box -->
        <!-- achtung hier soll man vielleicht die Adresse ändern -->
            <div class= &#39;small-box bg-blue&#39;>
                <div class="inner">
                    <h3>Station</h3>
                    <p> Model.ListStations[i]</p>
                </div>
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-heartbeat" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <a href= Station1 class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>            <div class= &#39;small-box bg-black&#39;>
                <div class="inner">
                    <h3>Station</h3>
                    <p> Model.ListStations[i]</p>
                </div>
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-heartbeat" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <a href= Station2 class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>            <div class= &#39;small-box bg-green&#39;>
                <div class="inner">
                    <h3>Station</h3>
                    <p> Model.ListStations[i]</p>
                </div>
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-heartbeat" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <a href= Station3 class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to check the generated HTML. Also, you didn't post the real code you are having issues with. From what I can see, the most probable issue is that you are not using double quotes for your tags.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing what the output HTML is.  I suggest inspecting the elements with the developer tools (right click on the box and select "inspect" in Chrome) and see if the classes on the elements are what you are expecting.

For example: It might be "working" correctly, but there's a typo in a generated class name.

Comment: Please share the generated HTML.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ I shared, but i don't know how to present a proper code on Stackoverflow ^^

Comment: @DoeJowns As you can see this is because you have `&#39;` instead of double-quotes

Comment: @DoeJowns In your `cshtml`, try to replace `<div class= "small-box bg-blue">` with `<div class="@(colorTemp)">`.

Comment: It works ! Thanks a lot :) !

Comment: By the way,  @ADreNaLiNe-DJ, have you an idea why all my icons are not displayed correctly ? ^^ ?

Comment: @DoeJowns You should check if FontAwesome is included correctly and then ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To share with others who can encounter this kind of problem, here is the solution.

In the generated `HTML`, there are `&#39;` instead of double-quotes.

To avoid this, you have to replace this `<div class= "small-box bg-blue">` with `<div class="@(colorTemp)">`